# Update a row each day in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'm doing a database for a tickets sell. Each user can sell and buy a ticket. If the seller doesn't send the ticket within 24 hour the sell is cancelled. I wanted to use Triggers but there's no date trigger in it. So, how can do something after a time ? I would like to reset a limitation of sell each month too for each user.

Comment: If you are running in Unix environment, schedule a simple cron job. Also, have a look at `pg_cron` extension https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron :

Comment: [pgAgent](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/en/8.4/pgadmin/pgagent.html) might be useful for you.

Comment: Don't delete the expired sales, but write your queries so that they ignore expired sales.